# Prevent Jquery-UI from changing styles in bootstrap nav-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built this menu with bootstrap. There is a dropdown menu that has a picture in it and next to it is a dropdown menu. On smaller resolutions, this dropdown menu arrow changes shape to a box. I want it to retain the shape of an arrow. However, something in Jquery-ui.js file is causing it to change shape on smaller resolutions.  How can I prevent the jquery-ui from affecting the arrow shape? Here is the code and attached are the snapshots

[Arrow shape before and after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/852aM.gif)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="market.html"><img  src="images/logo-inner.jpg"/ alt="B-Hive: Expand your business"></a> </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 

    <!-- Form search start -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" class="top-search-padding">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="search-div ui-widget"  >
        <input id="tags" type="text" class="txt-search" placeholder="Search people, products and services">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-search"><img src="images/search-icon.png"/></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Form search end -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="top-menu-links"><a href="#">MARKET</a></li>
      <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>
      <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">MESSAGES</a></li>
      <li><a class="top-menu-links" href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
      <li class="profile-pic-padding"></li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img alt = ""   class=" img-profile-pic img-circle" src="images/profile-pic.fw.png"/> <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Switch Accounts</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ع</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the css as `!important`, this cannot then be overridden

Comment: Thanks so much @ben_mj.  I'm now struggling to figure out exactly where in the bootstrap.css file do I need to apply the !important tag.  I know it is the .caret class, and have unsuccessfully tried at several instances. Any help here please?  Remember, it is only on the smaller resolutions.

Comment: Hard to say without a working example to debug. Have you tried inspecting the element to ensure you are targeting the correct class? It would be worth checking the css class on both large and small resolutions. Good Luck!

Comment: Never mind, I got it :)  Thanks so much for helping out.